# Remote work should have two options for companies

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I really love the Job section on Stack. After some tests where I applied for few jobs I realized one issue that makes the whole experience not so fun.

Companies have the ability to set if they are ok with `remote work`. But it turns out that they think the `Remote` tag as something completely different.

- To them, they think of someone that works in the same state as they do :D no joke this is what I got from multiple companies.
- To me `Remote Work` means I'm going to work from any place around the world.

It be nice if this tag was more clear to them and to the developer

- Remote Local
- Remote World

Something like that so it is clear where to apply for a job.

Comment: Agree this could be clearer. We don't have plans to work on this at the moment, but I will update this post if/when this is added to our roadmap.